# Adding a seed to random sphinx search

Tags: search, random, sphinx, random-seed

I am attempting to return a random series of results for a Sphinx search, but add a seed to @random so that results are maintained over a paginated set of results.

Currently, we are retrieving a random set of results using the following code:

```
SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "@random ASC");
```

Is it possible to add a seed to this random sorting mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware Sphinx added **rand_seed** option just a while ago that may serve your purpose.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/sphinxql-select.html

Mind you, it'll be only in the one of the newer builds of Sphinx.